# unordered_set: invalid operands to binary expression ('const Play' and 'const Play')

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I'm getting this error when I try to insert an element into an unordered_set:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const Play' and 'const Play')
        {return __x == __y;}
```

Here's a screenshot of the whole error:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nxq5skjm5mvzav3/Screenshot%202013-11-21%2020.11.24.png

This is my hash function:

```
struct Hash {

        size_t operator() (Play &play) {

            unsigned long hash = 5381;
            int c;

            string s_str = play.get_defense_name() + play.get_offense_name() + play.get_description();
            const char * str = s_str.c_str();

            while ( (c = *str++) )
                hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

            cout << hash << endl;
            return hash;

       }
    };
```

This is where I declare the unordered_list:

```
unordered_set<Play, Hash> Plays;
```

And this is my overloaded `==` for my `Play` class:

```
friend bool operator== (Play& p1, Play& p2)
    {
        return 
            (p1.get_defense_name() == p2.get_defense_name()) && 
            (p1.get_offense_name() == p2.get_offense_name()) &&
            (p1.get_description() == p2.get_description()); 
    }
```

Any idea what could be going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: try changing the signature of your `operator==` to use `const`.  As in, `friend bool operator==(const Play& p1, const Play& p2)`. It is best practice for logical operators to never change the objects they are comparing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the error is saying it try to compare `const Play` with `const Play` but you only provide `operator ==` for `Play`

```
friend bool operator== (const Play& p1, const Play& p2)
    {
        return 
            (p1.get_defense_name() == p2.get_defense_name()) && 
            (p1.get_offense_name() == p2.get_offense_name()) &&
            (p1.get_description() == p2.get_description()); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like unordered set is looking to compare constant `Play` objects, but your `==` offers to compare non-const ones. Since dropping const-ness is not allowed, the compiler produces an error. Adding const-ness should fix the problem:

```
friend bool operator== (const Play& p1, const Play& p2)
```

You should add `const` to your `operator()` as well:

```
size_t operator() (const Play &play)
```